# Input does not exit in c, thus output does not work

Tags: c, input, output, eof

I am just learning c, and I am using Linux terminal. I have written the following simple code, but when I type the inputs, the file does not exit and thus does not count the number of characters. Can anyone help me with it? I have tried other input codes as well. It's the same with all my input related codes. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

```
main()
{    
    /* count characters in input */    
    printf("Type some characters and the program will count the number of characters: ");

    int c = getchar();

    while(c!=EOF && c!= '\n')    
        ++c;

    printf("Number of characters typed: %1d\n", c);    
}
```

Comment: You only ever read one single character as you only call `getchar` once. You need to call it repeatedly as long as you don't encounter `EOF` (or `\n` or whatever is your stop condition, maybe `while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)` ?

Comment: What is this getchar() function ? The way to take input is normaly through a scanf("%s", buffer) which will take input and copy it in the variable **buffer**

Comment: @Yvain `getchar` is a standard function defined in stdio.h; if the OP wants to read char by char scanf("%s") isn't really appropriate.

Comment: You're also using the same variable for the count of characters as the input character. How could that possibly work?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the silly mistake @Barmar. I was going crazy over it! It's friday night afterall! 

Updated code:
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int c;

printf("Type some characters: ");

while(getchar()!=EOF && getchar()!= '\n')
++c;

printf("Total characters typed=  %1d \n", c);

}

Answer (score 0):

So to take notice of the helpful comments;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int c;
        int count = 0;

        while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                count++;
        printf("%d\n", count);
};
```

This code works as expected.

Comment: Are you saying `while((c=getchar()) != '\n' || c != EOF)` should be used? Wouldn't it be an endless loop as all characters, even `'\n'` and `EOF` are not equal to either and will make the condition always `true`.

Comment: No, this loop means: "as long as the input char is **neither** 'newline' **nor** 'EOF'", if you replaced or with and it would mean "as long as the input is not 'newline' **combined** with 'EOF'", so this one would never stop indeed.

Comment: You got that wrong buddy. Let's say `c` is `'\n`'. Your condition will evaluate as `while('\n' != '\n' || '\n' != EOF)` ===> `while(false || true)` ===> `while(true)`. Now let's see if `c` is `EOF`, `while(EOF != '\n' || EOF != EOF)` ===> `while(true || false)` ===> `while(true)`. For everything else `while(true || true)`. When will the loop end? I can't believe I have to type the evaluation of the code here.